# Argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type char*

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I keep receiving this error and unsure how to fix it. I'm new to C programming and tried searching through the book/internet and couldn't find much help. I'm trying to create a program that will print a grade report using a loop and a sctructure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Grades
{
    char Name[20];
    char Hrs;
    int ID;
    char ClassName[20];
    char Grade;
    char ClassID[6];
};

int main ()
{
    struct Grades Transcript[6];
    int classCnt = 0;
    int vHrs=0;
    char vGrade[2];
    char vName[20], vCID[6], vClassName[20];

    printf("Enter Students Name: ");
    fgets(vName, 20, stdin);

    do
    {   printf("Enter Class ID; ");
        fgets(vCID, 6, stdin);
        strcpy_s(Transcript[classCnt].ClassID, vCID);
        printf("Enter Class Name: ");
        fgets(vClassName, 20, stdin);
        strcpy_s(Transcript[classCnt].ClassName, vClassName);
        printf("Enter Class Hours: ");
        scanf("%d", &vHrs);
        strcpy(Transcript[classCnt].Hrs, vHrs);         //Problem occurs here
        printf("Enter Class Grade: ");
        scanf("%c", vGrade);
        strcpy(Transcript[classCnt].Grade, vGrade);     //Problem occurs here
        classCnt++;
    }while(classCnt<=6);
}
```

Comment: `char` and `char*` are two different types.  Understanding the difference is just about the first thing you must learn when learning C.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a number of problems here:

First, [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) is used to copy a string, if you have a character and you want it to assign it, you can simply assign it with the `=` operator. The [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) function is used when you have a character array you want to assign.

So your first problem

```
strcpy(Transcript[classCnt].Hrs, vHrs);
```

`Hrs` from your struct is just a `char` type, and `vHrs` is an `int` type. You can simply assign it like:

```
Transcript[classCnt].Hrs = vHrs;
```

However, an `int` can hold a lot more data than a `char` can, this is going to give you a warning about overflow and you should listen to it (depending on the implementation `char` holds -128 to 127, where as `int` holds −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647). Decide what data type you really wanted here and either make `Hrs` an `int` or `vHrs` a `char` then just do the assignment.

Second problem:

```
scanf("%c", vGrade);
```

`vGrade` as a character array (it is made up of more than one character) that means you should assign it with the string format operator `"%s"`, but when you do a string you should make the array long enough for the number of characters you want + 1 (for the NULL terminator).

Third problem:

```
strcpy(Transcript[classCnt].Grade, vGrade);
```

`Grade` is a `char` whereas `vGrade` is an array. Again, you have to make a decision of type, if you wanted a "string" of characters then you need to make them both arrays, if you wanted just a single character then change the type of `vGrade` and do a simple assignment with the `=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're running into here is a data typing error.

The structure member `.Hrs` is of type `"char"`.  The argument to `strcpy` is a `"char *"`.  Think of it like this:  A `char` is a single 8 byte number representing a value in ASCII.  A `"char *"` is a pointer to an array of characters (or a string in C language).

The Above is traditionally true,but , today it might be a unicode or multi-byte character string, as well.  In either case, what you need is the assignment operator (`=`), not a `strcpy`.

So you're telling `strcpy` to look at a single value (`char`), not a string of values (`char *`) which is it expecting as it's argument.  In this case, you can just copy the value of the integer you scanned in with `scanf` directly.

```
Transcript[classCnt].Hrs = vHrs;
```

and

```
Transcript[classCnt].Grade = vGrade;
```

If you're looking for the best book ever written, well in my opinion anyway :-), on C Language, check out:
C Programming Language (2nd Edition)  - Looks like it's available on Amazon (or at you're favorite used book seller) for about $21 (USD).